# RecyclerView Android, установка высоты элементов

Tags: android, xml

Мне надо отобразить на экране 6 элементов одного типа(они сложные и состоят из набора простых view). 2 столбца и 3 строки. Назовем условно их CustomView. Я могу сверстать в xml отдельно каждый CustomView и поместить в root, а могу сделать это через RecyclerView. Преимущества RecyclerView очевидны, однако мне важно чтобы на экране было видно все 6 элементов без надобности прокручивать экран вниз. Если я верстаю каждый элемент вручную, без использования RecyclerView, то я просто делю экран с помощью веса в LinearLayout. Подозреваю что через RecyclerView тот же эффект достигается установкой высоты элементов(с шириной тут понятно, просто через GridLayoutManager). Вопрос: как мне это сделать через RecyclerView.
P.S. Мои CustomView сверстаны так, что автоматически принимают адекватный вид в зависимости от высоты.

Comment: Не могу сказать, что очевидны преимущества RecyclerView, так как он создан немного для другого. Если использовать его - будет небольшой гемморой с выислением высоты и ширины элементов. Если же будешь наполнять вьюху динамически высоту и ширину элементов можно оставить разметке.

Comment: Если хочешь использовать RecyclerView смотри в сторону LayoutParams, ты можешь назначить парамсы с нужной шириной и высотой itemView в вью холдере при инициализации

Comment: Просто если не использовать recyclerview, то придется верстать 6 одинаковых элементов. И если я вдруг захочу поменять что-то, то придется опять же все 6 элементов переделывать.

Comment: Можно наверстать один и написать для него вью холдер )